# Finding Voltage of a Circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I am self studying circuit analysis, and got the following question wrong:

[image]

Since the 12 Volt battery's negative terminal connects to ground, V1 must equal 12.

The current i should equal the voltage drop between V1 and V2 + 8 (since we know V2 is a drop of 8 Volts from the other side the battery) divided by the resistor's resistance in ohms.

So i = (V1 - (V2 + 8))/6.

Then V2 = V1 - 6i - 8

I am now stuck.  V2 is defined in terms of i and i is defined in terms of V2.

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong, or other tools I can use?  I've tried nodal analysis to no avail.

I know the answer is 1.6 V, but I want to understand why.

Comment: !.6 V is the answer to what?

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using [Kirchhoff’s voltage law](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/kirchhoffs-voltage-law.html) we have

$$12-4i-8-6i=0,$$

the negative $8V$ comes from the battery being connected in reverse with respect to the 12V.

Rearranging for $i$ gives

$$i=\frac{4}{10}=0.4A.$$

And then by Ohm’s law $V2=4\times 4/10=1.6V$.

Comment: Hmmm, genius! you are saying basically "so what if there's an earthing, nothing changes"

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessary complicated analysis and not really answering the question and source of confusion which is that ideal voltage sources don't have a voltage drop therefore their voltage output across their leads is not affected by the current in series.

An ideal voltage source has no voltage drop (zero internal resistance). This is depicted in your schematic.

Your equivalent circuit is just an ideal source 4V with a total of 10 ohm resistance load connected in series. Current *I*,  is 0.4A.

Voltage sources connected in series with their like polarity leads are subtracted.

Separate voltages drops in the 6 ohm and 4 ohm resistance are 2.4V and 1.6V respectively.

When you go with a voltmeter to measure the voltage on the connected in the circuit ideal voltage sources, you will measure for the ideal 12V source +12V and for the ideal 8V source -8V.

Here is the circuit simulation on [https://www.circuitlab.com](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/) :

[image]

Across the positive lead of V2 8V source and GND you will measure 9.6V and across the negative lead of V2 8V and and GND 1.6V.

Answer (score 0):

i = (12-8)/(6+4) = 4/10=0.4A

So according to Ohm's law since V2 is electrically 'seperated' from ground only by R2 and current i flows through R2 V2  = ixR2 = 4x0.4=1.6V

Comment: So is i the current going through the entire circuit?  I assume you're doing total voltage of the opposing batteries, 4, divided by the total resistance in the circuit equals the current going through the entire circuit?

I think one point of confusion I have is, is the current the same everywhere?  Or is i like an average circuit?

Comment: if the current were different at differnt points in the simple single loop circuit, then charge would  "pile up" at some point towards infinity

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "Zero Potential Method" by assuming the left-corner point as zero volts. Then V2 = 12V like you mentioned. So you get these two equations.
$$\ i = \frac {12-8-V2}{6}$$
$$\ i = \frac {V2}{4}$$
The second equation is true because the current is the same throughout the circuit due to Kirchhoff's Current Law

Solve for the value of i and you will get V2 = 4i = 1.6V